# Access to Set Up Menu

Tags: permissions, profile, setup

Can someone tell me what permission/profile setting determines whether that person will be able to navigate to "Set up" page or not ?

*Surprisingly I am unable to find answer to this in a simple google search.
I get results with respect to visualforce pages, force.com sites and even page layouts except this one :)*

EDIT :

I am referring to the below
[image]

Comment: Which setup pages? Different parts are determined by different permissions on profiles.

Comment: Tx..Updated my post.

Answer (score 2):

**View Setup and Configuration permission** in profile setting determines whether that person will be able to navigate to "Set up" page or not.

[image]